# Nginx equivalent to mod_security and related

Tags: security, nginx

I'm looking for a way to get my nginx to have reasonable abilities for auto-blocking various malicious requests.

E.g. since it doesn't serve any php scripts, any request for a php URLs that script kiddies seem to direct to my server should result in an immediate (temporary) ban of that IP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

update, mod_security now available for nginx:
http://www.modsecurity.org/projects/modsecurity/nginx/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). It scans log files and can update firewall rules to ban specific IP. Also, it can execute any other action if needed.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know [Naxsi](http://code.google.com/p/naxsi/) is the only web application firewall solution for Nginx at the moment. It does not rely on signatures, but instead it detects unexpected characters in the HTTP communication. It also comes with a learning daemon that can be used to generate profiles for your applications.